# How extensive is an Object in CakePHP model linkage?

Tags: cakephp, model, associations, linkage

I was hoping someone with an understanding on CakePHP could shed some light on a question I've been having.

Here's my scenario, I have a `User` this `User` has a `Company` which in turn has many `Department` and many `Address`. If I were to get a `User` could I expect to have access to the `Company` and all models associated with that `Company`?

So would `$user['Company']['Department'][0]` or `$user['Company']['Address'][0]` be possible?

Which brings me back to the original question, how extensive is the linkage between models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain-vanilla model, Cake's model linkage is determined by your models' `recursive` attribute. Your example model relationship looks something like this:

```
User
-> belongsTo Company
   -> hasMany Department
   -> hasMany Address
-> hasMany PhoneExtension
```

(I've added an additional relationship (`User hasMany PhoneExtension`) to flesh out the following explanation.)

There are three accepted values for `Model::recursive`: -1, 0, 1 and 2. Each value indicates to Cake's ORM a different depth to retrieve model records. I'll use `$this->User->find('all')` to illustrate the difference.

- At `recursive = -1`, Cake retrieves only the specified model (ie. `User`). It parses none of the model associations.
- At `recursive = 0`, Cake retrieves the specified model, and parses its `belongsTo` associations. `$this->User->find('all')` would retrieve all `User` records, as well as the `Company` record to which each `User` belongs.
- At `recursive = 1`, Cake retrieves the specified model, and parses all of its direct associations. `$this->User->find('all')` would retrieve all `User` records, as well as the `Company` record to which each `User` belongs, and all `PhoneExtension` records belonging to the `User`.
- At `recursive = 2`, Cake retrieves the specified model, parses all of its direct associations *and* all associations of its direct associations. `$this->User->find('all')` would retrieve everything in the example model relationship diagram: all `User` records, the `Company` records to which the `User` records belong, all `PhoneExtension` records belonging to the `User`, and all `Department` and `Address` records belonging to the `Company`.

Which is the very long way of saying that yes, you can achieve the results you indicate in your question, at `recursive = 2`.

If you wanted to go *deeper* than what `recursive = 2` gets you, you'll have to use the [`Containable` behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable). Let's say that your `Department` model had an additional association: `hasMany Group`. Thus:

```
User
-> belongsTo Company
   -> hasMany Department
      -> hasMany Group
   -> hasMany Address
-> hasMany PhoneExtension
```

To retrieve everything we got with a `recursive = 2` retrieval, as well as all the associated `Group` records, you'd construct your `Model::find` call like this:

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array( 
        'PhoneExtension',
        'Company' => array(
            'Department' => array( 'Group' ),
            'Address'
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as extensive as you need/want it to be. Look into the `recursive` option of the `find()` family of methods. Also the `Containable` behavior. The specific references you list are possible, but directly under the user:

```
$user['Department'][0]
```

Think of it as the user having many departments *through* its company.

Answer (score 0):

If you access a class/object and set "`$this->recursive = -1`" then it only returns the object without the dependencies!